# if we use Azure Service bus with SessionId is slower than without ? Or do they have the same speed

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm using service bus service From azure to Send Messages and I was wondering if Using SessionId will effect the speed of sending messages than the Case if I dont use it.
I know that SessionId will preserve the Order but what about the all in all speed ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending a message will not be much slower when you specify a session ID. Processing will be, but this is the wrong terminology to use. You can't compare handling messages w/o a session by multiple concurrent consumers and sessioned messages where the intent is to process those messages in the order they were sent in. Different business requirements that have different justifications, right? If you plan to use sessions, processing will be somewhat slower due to only a single active consumer being able to process all the messages from a given session. And that has to be backed up by a requirement, probably.

Take, for example handling items scanned at a grocery checkout. If you want to know what items are purchased in general, competing consumers is the way to go. However, if you want to know what items were bought per purchase, you can't use a competing consumer and have to use sessions to ensure only items for a given purchase are included and nothing else. Will the latter be somewhat slower? Yes, but you can't accomplish it with a competing consumer and if the business wants it, they'll accept the cost of slightly slower processing to gain the insights. Note, there are always multiple ways to solve the problem and maybe sessions is not what's needed at all.